# EF6.1.1 with MySQL connection does not close

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I have a **WPF** (with `MahApps.Metro` and `Caliburn.Micro`) project using **Entity Framework 6.1.1** (Latest) and all of the latest `MySQL`.

Whenever i run my project it opens up a new connection to the mysql server, but as i exit the application the connection remains open and goes to sleep. Entering a new debug session opens up a new connection whilst the other remains asleep.

How can i make sure the connection gets closed properly upon exiting my application so i don't end up hitting my connection limit?

**Query method**

```
public void RetrieveCourses()
        {
            // Query database
            var context = new TAModelContainer();
            var data = context.Courses.ToList<Course>();

            foreach (Course course in data)
            {
                _courses.Add(course);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can we see your code that uses the database?

Comment: I use very simple Linq queries, i shall update the post with a sample method. The rest is all model-first generated stuff from EF6 in a seperate class library project within my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dispose the context when you are done with it.  Not doing so can exhaust your Connection Pool and you may fail to get a connection.

```
    public void RetrieveCourses()
    {
        // Query database
        using(var context = new TAModelContainer())
        {
            var data = context.Courses.ToList<Course>();

            foreach (Course course in data)
            {
                _courses.Add(course);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. For some reason i figured EF would handle this for me.

Comment: By disposing your EF Context the Sql Connection you are using gets returned to the Connection Pool.  EF uses a Connecton Pool to speed up your DB connections.  Connections in the Pool are kept open to the DB so that when you need one you don't have to go through Authentication which can slow things down.  Best practice is to open your DB Connections and Dispose them as soon as you can.